# Contingency table and confusion matrix: Am I doing it right?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

In epidemiology, we mainly write the True class on the column side. We can then compare the performance predictions or tests against the gold standard screening tool/truth value (See figure below).

[image]

I am confused with sklearn confusion matrix tables. In sklearn, we normally write it as

```
confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred)
```

Displaying the result of this confusion matrix using ConfusionMatrixDisplay looks like the following (see figure)

[image]

Sklearn puts the predictions on the column side which adds confusion to my interpretations(coming from an epidemiology background). If I reverse the order of y_test and pred in the confusion matrix function, I can obtain a table similar to the contingency table's standard format.

```
confusion_matrix(y_pred,y_test)  # reverse order of arguments
```

My question is,
I can reverse the order in `confusion_matrix()` and get a confusion matrix that looks like the "standard" contingency table. But, am I doing it right?

Comment: I know they are not interchangeable. Then, I don't need to bother about the classification report. Does that mean it is ok to reverse the order in the confusion matrix but not in the classification report?

Comment: Why you even need to mess up wit the classification report? I get the issue with the "transposed" CM which is not in the epidemiology format and may thus create confusion, but why bothering at all with the classification report here? Why the info provided is *not* enough as-is? And since you know the arguments are not interchangeable, why asking "why"? Is "why" really the *actual* question you want to ask?

Comment: In other words, what stops you from calling `confusion_matrix()` with the reverse order of arguments (since this seems to resolve the "transpose" issue), while using `classification_report()` with the correct order of arguments? Why these two seemingly unrelated problems are related?

Comment: Well, I edited the question. I asked because I am in confusion. It might be obvious for you but not for me. I beg your pardon if that is offending. But, asking obviously is costing us a thing here.